# Summing rows based on date conditional and create a new row with the result

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```py
order_creation_time  order_id   device_id                               error  status creation_time_device
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:59:55
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:58:50
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:58:28
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:58:08
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:57:53
```

Each `device_id` receive N orders and every `order_id` came with its own `order_creation_time`, I want to know what was the behavior of the device after receiving that particular order.

For example, 3 minutes before the `order_id 102665113`, how many orders the device_id had received? and with that knowledge add a new column in the `order_id 102665113`

The idea is to make that sum with every `order_creation_time`.

Example Result:

```py
order_creation_time  order_id   device_id                               error  status creation_time_device orders_received
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:59:55    20
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:58:50    20
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:58:28    20
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:58:08    20
2020-02-26 23:54:41  102665113  c267767a-05df-4ca5-af6e-8fb6afdbb7b5    NaN    200  2020-02-26 23:57:53    20
```

I've been thinking the entire day about how to do this but I cannot figure out a good way. My idea right now is to iterate into every row of the data frame and compare every `order_creation_time`. But I'm not sure if there's a method that can make my life easier for this.

Thanks!

Comment: from the data shared, how do you compute the number of orders to be 20?

Comment: It was just an example of how the dataframe should looks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if it does what you want.

```py
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df['device_id'], df['order_id']])
df = df.drop(['device_id', 'order_id'], axis=1)
df['orders_received'] = df.groupby(['device_id', 'order_id']).size()
```

Comment: It may not, because I'm quite confident about your requirements, but it's too large to fit into a comment.